# how to redirect a.com to www.a.com?

Tags: domain-name-system, http

I am using nginx and want if user type a.com to access the web, it will be redirected to www.a.com, thanks.

Comment: IMO, it should be www.a.com -> a.com , www is redundant, its already the web.

Comment: I agree with Kent in that you should redirect from www to just example.com.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you take a look at the [HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) and implement one that redirects all requests to a.com to www.a.com, preserving the original path.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
server {
    server_name  a.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.a.com$1 permanent;
}
```

The permanent attribute makes nginx redirect by HTTP 301 instead of (I think) 302.

Comment: It can't because i have clf.a.com such domains already...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the rewrite rule from ["Converting rewrite rules"](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html), you can use the following rewrite rule:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  a.com;
    rewrite   ^  http://www.a.com$request_uri?;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest way to do this is at the DNS level and have the web server accept requests for both. No need to stuff around with rewriting.